# Given an electric potential in curved spacetime, how to calculate the total electric charge?

Tags: electromagnetism, charge, potential, curvature

In general $d$ dimensional setup ($d-1$ spatial coordinates and $1$ temporal), with a nontrivial metric $g_{\mu\nu}(t,\vec{r})$, having for simplicity a static electric potential $\phi(\vec{r})$.
How to calculate the electric charge that is the source of this potential?

I know that when considering classical physics, the charge $Q$ is given by the spatial integration on the laplacian of the potential over all the space $V$:

$$Q=-\int_V \nabla^2\phi(\vec{r})d\vec{r}$$

Three options make sense to me when moving to curved spacetime:

1. There is no change at all and we can calculate it as the classical integration above
2. All the components of the metric should be taken into account according to $$Q = -\int_V d^{d-1}r \sqrt{-g}g^{\mu\nu}\nabla_\mu\partial_{\nu}\phi(\vec{r})$$
   Here $\mu,\nu\in\{\vec{r},t\}$
   Where $\nabla_\mu$ is the covariant derivative which operate on a vector field $\partial_{\nu}\phi(\vec{r})$ as follow:
   $$\nabla_\mu\partial_{\nu}\phi(\vec{r})=\partial_\mu\partial_{\nu}\phi(\vec{r})-\Gamma^{\alpha}_{\mu\nu}\partial_{\alpha}\phi(\vec{r}) $$
   and
   $g=\det{g_{\mu\nu}}$
3. Only the spatial part of the metric is joining the spatial integration:
   $$Q = - \int_V d^{d-1}r \sqrt{-\tilde{g}}\tilde{g}^{\mu\nu}\nabla_\mu\partial_{\nu}\phi(\vec{r})$$
   Here $\mu,\nu\in\{\vec{r}\}$
   Where $\tilde{g}$ represents the spatial part of the metric, such that, the full metric is given by:
   $$g_{\mu\nu}=\begin{pmatrix}
    g_{tt} & g_{t\vec{r}} \\
    g_{\vec{r}t} & \tilde{g}_{\vec{r}\vec{r}} \\
   \end{pmatrix}$$

From (1)-(3) what is the right way to calculate the total charge?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The invariant equation for the induction field (tangent 2-form at the surface of a conducting sphere) is

$$D = D_{ik}(t,x) dx^i\wedge dx^k : \quad  D = \frac {q}{4 \pi r^2}  \sin \theta d\phi\wedge d \theta$$

It counts the charge inside any sphere by

$$\int_{r*S^2} D = \int_{\phi,\theta \in S^2} \frac {q}{4 \pi }  \sin \theta d\phi\wedge d \theta = q $$

D has a Hodge dual, metric product with the volume 4-form, independent of $r$   with zero exterior derivative.

$$E=*D = \left< dct\wedge dr \wedge r \sin \theta d\phi \wedge r d\theta ,D\right> = \frac {q}{4 \pi} dct \wedge dr  $$

with $d E  = 0$ in vacuum.

Exctly these set of equations can be transferred to any pseudo-Riemann 4-manifold.

If the manifold is spacelike open, the integral over any n-1-sphere of a Cauchy (spacelike) n-space  (at constant time) yields the charge inside.

If the manifold has no spacelike boundaries and is simply connected, the total charge must be zero.

Confer Misner/Thorne/Wheeler, Gravitation chpt 2: Forms and electromagnetism.

The classical expositions by mostauthors, using Riemannian manifolds with vector fields, are as confusing, as are the classical tables of vector field differential algebra for the student.

Comment: Can you write it in terms of metric tensor?
I hate the differential geometry notations including all those Hodge duals they are like Chinese to me